# UITableview scroll offset on an empty tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm trying to offset a uitableview similar to what you'd do if you have a search bar that you'd like to have hide by default. My problem is that I'd like the offset to exist even when the tableview is empty. I'm currently using something like this :

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, normalHeaderHeight)];
```

Which works, unless the tableview is empty. (I've got a uisegmented control that filters tableview and i'd like for it not to "jump" awkwardly when the tableview is empty.

My one thought is to add a uitableview footer that ensures there is scrollable distance. Don't know if someone's already written something like that, or if there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`UIEdgeInsets`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html). You can set the `top` to the size of your `normalHeaderHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

put  `setContentOffset` in `viewDidAppear` , it should work.